# $\frac{1}{z^2-2z+2}$ - $\max_{z \in D(0,1)} |f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

Let the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-2z+2}$. Compute $\max_{z \in D(0,1)} |f(z)|$ where $D(0,1)$ is an open disk.

Honnestly, I just really don't know how to solve this problem. Maybe in using the Cauchy inequality theorem.

Is anyone could give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is $D(0,1)$ the closed unit disc or open unit disc?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski It is an open disk

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum. $f$ has simple poles at $1+i$ and $1-i$, so it is holomorphic on $D(0,1)$.  $|f(z)|$ can only obtain a maximum on the boundary $\overline D\setminus D$.

Comment: What do you mean by simple poles?

Comment: Simple poles are singularities $a$ such that $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$ and $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)\ne\infty$.

Comment: Which results allow  you to conclude your main argument?

Comment: @RobertDavis It's called the Maximum Modulus Principle.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle